# Cannot resolve method "setMultichoiceItem" error

Tags: java, android

I am learning Android from some book and keep  getting error on .setMultichoiceItem block  : **cannot resolve method .setMultichoiceItems** . 
 I check it over multiple times and my code is all case sensitive, and no misspelled words.

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    CharSequence[] items = {"Google","Safari","Yahoo"};
    Boolean[] itemChecked = new Boolean[items.length];
    Button btn ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(0);


            }
        });
    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)

                        .setTitle("Test of Dialog")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "OK Clicked !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancel Clicked !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        })

                            .setMultiChoiceItems(items, itemChecked,
                                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[which] + (isChecked ? " checked!" : " unchecked!"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }

                                    }).create();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Logcat Error** : **Cannot resolve method 'setMultiChoiceItems(java.lang.CharSequence[], java.lang.Boolean[], android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener)'**

Any help would be awesome .

Thanks

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'setMultiChoiceItems(java.lang.CharSequence[], java.lang.Boolean[], android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener)'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this one,

Change this line
`Boolean[] itemChecked = new Boolean[items.length];`
to

```
boolean[] itemChecked = new boolean[items.length];
```

because its second parameter accepts boolean[], not Boolean[] objects

```
setMultiChoiceItems(CharSequence[] items, boolean[] checkedItems, DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener listener)
```

Answer (score 1):

import android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener;

Answer (score 1):

I found the better solution:

```
    public void alertMultipleChoiceItems(){
    final CharSequence[] dialogList = Symbollist.toArray(new CharSequence[Symbollist.size()]);
    HashSet<String> uniqueValues = new HashSet<>(Symbollist);
    Symbollist.clear();
    for (String value : uniqueValues) {
        //... //Do something
        Symbollist.add(value);
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddPackageStep3.this);
    selectedItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // set the dialog title
    boolean[] itemChecked = new boolean[selectedItems.size()];

    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(dialogList,null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                    if (isChecked) {
                        // if the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                        selectedItems.add(which);
                    }

                    else if (selectedItems.contains(which)) {
                        // else if the item is already in the array, remove it
                        selectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                    }

                    // you can also add other codes here,
                    // for example a tool tip that gives user an idea of what he is selecting
                    // showToast("Just an example description.");
                }

            })
            // Set the action buttons
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    // user clicked OK, so save the mSelectedItems results somewhere
                    // here we are trying to retrieve the selected items indices
                    String selectedIndex = "";
                    for(Integer i : selectedItems){
                        selectedIndex += i + ", ";
                    }

                    //showToast("Selected index: " + selectedIndex);

                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // removes the AlertDialog in the screen
                }
            })
            .show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to **boolean** Array this way by using the Guava:

```
  boolean[] listBoolean = Booleans.toArray(checkedList);
```